# Effect of reorthonormalisation step size when calculating Lyapunov exponents using the Gram–Schmidt reorthonormalisation (GSR) procedure

Tags: data-analysis, chaos-theory, complex-systems

I am trying to determine the Lyapunov exponent using Gram–Schmidt reorthonormalisation (GSR), for a well-defined dynamical system (I know the differential equations etc). I believe I have implemented it correctly, however I am unsure about the choice of when to renormalise the perturbation vectors. It seems I could pick any time to renormalise, each having a large influence on my results. Renormalising every step for example would make my answer tend to 0 upon taking logarithms.

My first question is: Does this really matter, when I am trying to determine chaos? In this case, the most important aspect is the sign and not necessarily the magnitude (I believe the value will be small for my system anyways). Secondly, is there a standard procedure people undertake to tackle this problem? I cannot find any clear resources.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

> i am unsure about the choice of when to renormalise the perturbation vectors

The best choice is system dependent, so you'll have to go with trial-and-error if starting with no previous knowledge.

FWIW, for calculating the Lyapunov exponents (LE) for the Lorenz system with some standard parameter values, J. C. Sprout [chose](https://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/chaos/WOLFFLOW.BAS) 20 integration steps per reorthonormalization step and, in some 20-year-old code of mine, renormalizing every time unit also seemed good enough.

> i could pick any time to renormalise, each having a large influence on my results

Nope. On the contrary: If your LEs are varying with your renormalization time step, it's a sign this step is too big.

> renormalising every step for example would make my answer tend to 0

It shouldn't: Remember that with smaller intervals the factors will indeed be smaller, but you'll have more of them — it should balance out.

Answer (score 1):

> the Lyapunov exponent

If you wish to compute only the largest Lyapunov exponent, you do not need reorthonormalisation at all. This is only needed for further Lyapunov exponents on account of the first Lyapunov vector (the direction of largest expansion) bleeding into the others due to numerical inaccuracies.

You only need renormalisation to keep the perturbation small compared to the dynamics.

> is there a standard procedure people undertake to tackle this problem, as I cannot find any clear resources.

The standard procedure in your case would arguably be the method from [Benettin et al.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02128236) It uses tangent vectors (representing infinitesimal perturbations) instead of perturbations. The propagation of these tangent vectors uses the Jacobian of your dynamics, so you have to be able to compute that.

Since the size of the tangent vectors doesn’t affect their growth or shrinking, you only need renormalisation to avoid numerical over- or underflows (and you only need reorthogonalisation for higher Lyapunov exponents due to the reasons mentioned above).

Blatant self-advertisement: If you wish to compare results, I have written a [module](https://github.com/neurophysik/jitcode) which implements Bennetin’s method, including computing the Jacobian. You still need to choose the reorthonormalisation times sufficiently small though (by choosing the integration steps).

> It seems i could pick any time to renormalise, each having a large influence on my results (renormalising every step for example would make my answer tend to 0 upon taking logarithms).

I don’t know which definition of the Lyapunov exponent you are using, but a typical one would be (for the largest one):

$$λ = \lim_{τ→∞} \lim_{|x(t)-y(t)| →0} \frac{1}{τ} \ln \left( \frac{|x(t+τ)-y(t+τ)}{|x(t)-y(t)|} \right),$$

where $x$ and $y$ are two trajectories (orbits) of your dynamics.

In the basic orbit-separation approach (you appear to be using), you choose your initial perturbation $|x(t)-y(t)|$ small instead of infinitesimal.
Therefore you cannot let the evolution time $τ$ go towards infinity.
Instead you average over many initial conditions $t$ (one after each renormalisation).
This is a valid approximation and the problem you are afraid of does not occur as you divide by $τ$ in the definition of the Lyapunov exponent.

Choosing overly small reorthonormalisation steps should not have a negative effect on your results (unless they are so absurdly small, that the effect of the dynamics becomes numerically zero). The main drawback is that it can drastically increase your computation time.